# permission returning null in react native app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, android-permissions

When I requested MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE getting a null permission error. in react native app. when I went throw the document (https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid) there is no permission like this, but actually, for accessing hidden files we need this permission.
If i gave the same permission in androidmanifest.xml file not even asking the user.

[image]

manifest file

```js
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```js
const pm1 = await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE); // 
    const pm2 = await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    const pm3 = await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE); // ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION

    if (pm1 && pm2) return true
    const userResponse = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.at,
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ]);
```

Comment: You cannot request permission in the usual way for manage external storage. Instead you should launch an intent for the settings of it so the user can confirm.

Comment: why i can't ?? it is available in Android it seems ?

Answer (score 0):

As per google's new guidelines, we cant request MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission,This particular permission is only reserved for a few apps(like antivirus and file manager) only if you request this permission u need to give so much of an explanation to google play store, But if you still need this permission you can request by using below code this will help user to navigate permission page.

package: react-native-intent-launcher

```
 IntentLauncher.startActivity({
       action: 'android.settings.MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION',
       data: 'package:com.yourpackageNameHere'
     })
```